# Ionic 1 Keyboard pushes content up

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, keyboard, cordova-plugins

I have looked extensively on ways to fix this issue and I have tried many suggestions, but have yet to solve the problem. I have an Ionic 1 (1.7.16) app, which has a login page that has input fields. When the user taps on the input field the content on the page gets pushed out of view. Then when the keyboard is closed, the content aligns it self correctly.

I have installed the ionic keyboard and implemented  cordova.plugins.keyboard.disablescroll(true) and this does not work.

Here is an example of my function that runs when ionic is ready

```
 .run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
  // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
  // for form inputs)
  if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);
    cordova.plugins.keyboard.disablescroll(true)
  }
  if (window.StatusBar) {
    // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
    StatusBar.styleDefault();
  }
});
```

})

Here is the login page:

```
<ion-view view-title="Login" align-title="left">
<ion-content class="loginBackground">
    <div class="hero no-header flat">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="app-icon"></div>
            <h1>TEST</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="padding">
        <button class="button button-block icon-left ion-social-facebook button-positive" ng-click="facebookSignIn()">Login with Facebook</button>
    </div>
   <div class="list list-inset">

      <label class="item item-input">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="data.name">
      </label>

      <label class="item item-input">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="data.password">
      </label>

  </div>
    <div class="padding">
        <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
    </div>

     <!--Register Now button-->
     <div class="register">
     <button class="button button-block button-clear hide-on-keyboard-open" ng-click="register()">Not signed up? Register now!</button>
     </div>
  <!--END Register Now button-->
</ion-content>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is the default funtionality, the idea is to le the input you are filling right above the keyboard. What do you want it to do instead?